# enable/disable radio buttons in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am new to angularjs and learning to code. I have  section with three radio buttons and trying to disable other radio buttons on selecting one. Below is my code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class='info-container-content'>
  <div>
    <label class="info-container-accent" aria-label="Search By Zipcode and Radius">Search By Zipcode and Radius </label>
    <input type="radio" name="selectSearch" ng-model="type" />
    <input id="search-text-location" type='text' name='zip-location' ng-disabled="" aria-label="Enter Zip Code" placeholder='Enter Zip Code' ng-model="$ctrl.cservice.locsearch.ZipCode" ng-model-options="modelOptions" />
    <select name='zip-radius' aria-label="Radius from Zip Code" ng-disabled="" ng-model="$ctrl.cservice.locsearch.SearchRadius" ng-options="item as item.text for item in $ctrl.cservice.locsearch.SearchRadii track by item.value" ng-model-options="modelOptions"></select>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div>
    <label class="info-container-accent" aria-label="Search by County">Search by County</label>
    <input type="radio" name="selectSearch" ng-model="type" />
    <select name='loc-county' aria-label="County" ng-disabled="" ng-model="$ctrl.cservice.locsearch.County" ng-options="item as item.RegionName for item in $ctrl.cservice.locsearch.Counties track by item.RegionCode" ng-model-options="modelOptions">
                                <option value="">Select a County</option>
                            </select>
  </div>
  <br />
  <div>
    <label class="info-container-accent" class="info-container-accent" aria-label="Search by Properity Region">Search by Properity Region</label>
    <input type="radio" name="selectSearch" ng-model="type" />

    <select name='loc-region' aria-label="Region" ng-disabled="" ng-model="$ctrl.cservice.locsearch.Region" ng-options="item as item.RegionName for item in $ctrl.cservice.locsearch.Regions track by item.RegionCode" ng-model-options="modelOptions">
                                <option value="">Select a Region</option>
                            </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

kindly help.

Comment: So one question that must be asked: If you disable the other radio buttons when you select one of them, wouldn't that mean the user could only ever select one radio button? Seems kind of an odd user experience.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `ng-value` to set the value of each radio button as sample

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">

  <div class='info-container-content'>
    <div>
      <label class="info-container-accent" aria-label="Search By Zipcode and Radius">Search By Zipcode and Radius </label>
      
      <input type="radio" name="selectSearch" ng-model="type" ng-value="0" />
      
      <input id="search-text-location" type='text' name='zip-location' ng-disabled="type != 0" aria-label="Enter Zip Code" placeholder='Enter Zip Code' ng-model="$ctrl.cservice.locsearch.ZipCode" ng-model-options="modelOptions" />
      <select name='zip-radius' aria-label="Radius from Zip Code" ng-disabled="type != 0" ng-model="$ctrl.cservice.locsearch.SearchRadius" ng-options="item as item.text for item in $ctrl.cservice.locsearch.SearchRadii track by item.value" ng-model-options="modelOptions"></select>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
      <label class="info-container-accent" aria-label="Search by County">Search by County</label>
      <input type="radio" name="selectSearch" ng-model="type" ng-value="1"/>
      <select name='loc-county' aria-label="County" ng-disabled="type != 1" ng-model="$ctrl.cservice.locsearch.County" ng-options="item as item.RegionName for item in $ctrl.cservice.locsearch.Counties track by item.RegionCode" ng-model-options="modelOptions">
                                <option value="">Select a County</option>
                            </select>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
      <label class="info-container-accent" class="info-container-accent" aria-label="Search by Properity Region">Search by Properity Region</label>
      <input type="radio" name="selectSearch" ng-model="type" ng-value="2"/>

      <select name='loc-region' aria-label="Region" ng-disabled="type != 2" ng-model="$ctrl.cservice.locsearch.Region" ng-options="item as item.RegionName for item in $ctrl.cservice.locsearch.Regions track by item.RegionCode" ng-model-options="modelOptions">
                                <option value="">Select a Region</option>
                            </select>
    </div>
  </div>
type is : {{type}}
</div>
```